# If a value is present in a column and, for the same row, another column matches a certain value, then return a third value

Tags: excel, match, vlookup

I have an excel worksheet looking like this:

`ISO-Code; Main Sample
 IT             x
 DE             x
 GB

 US             x
 DK

 ES             x`

On another working sheet I also have the ISO country codes and I would need a column looking like this:

`ISO-Code; Main Sample
 IT             YES
 DE             YES
 GB             NO

 US             YES
 DK             NO 
 ES             YES`

Basically, if the country code in the second table can be retrieved in the first one and if the column "Main Sample" has an "x" for that country code, then we will have "YES" in the second column of the second table, otherwise, "NO".

I can not quite understand how to combine IF and VLOOKUP/MATCH function to have the output that I need.

Thank you!

Comment: Use IF and COUNTIFS for this. Or IF and VLOOKUP should work just fine - how is it not working for you?

Comment: @BigBen is right: =IF(COUNTIFS(Sheet1!A:A,"US",Sheet!B:B,"X")>0,"Yes","No")

Comment: Ok the combination of IF and COUNTIFS worked fine. Thanks! I would also need to left my output cell empty in case the ISO-code from the second table can not be retrieved in the first one.